# How to use spring.application.name in RestTemplate url on a docker container?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, microservices, netflix-eureka

I have two spring boot projects - `album-service` on port 8081 and `song-service` on port 8082 .

`song-service` has an entity class `Song` with the field `albumId`, which happens to be the primary key of the entity class `Album` in `album-service`.

I have a particular line in my service class `SongService` which returns an `Album` object by using RestTemplate:

```
Album album = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8082/find/"+song.getAlbumId(), Album.class);
```

Now, I thought to use application name instead of using `localhost:xxxx` on RestTemplate.

So in `application.yml` of `album-service` I wrote this line:

```
spring:
 application:
  name: ALBUM-SERVICE
```

and replaced the RestTemplate line with:

```
Album album = restTemplate.getForObject("http://ALBUM-SERVICE/find/"+song.getAlbumId(), Album.class);
```

This also seems to work just fine (when paired with a Eureka server and having `album-service` and `song-service` as Eureka clients), when both projects are running.

HOWEVER, issues come when these projects are on separate docker containers. When I run the API which uses the above line containing RestTemplate, I get an exception:

```
2021-05-03 11:14:51.588 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://ALBUM-SERVICE/albums/find/1": Connection refused; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused] with root cause
```

Here are the config files for everything:

1. `application.yml` of `album-service`:

```
server:
  port: 8081

spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      host: mongodb-container
      port: 27017
      database: music
  application:
    name: ALBUM-SERVICE

eureka:
  client:
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://service-registry-container:8761/eureka/

  instance:
    hostname: service-registry-container
```

2. `application.yml` of `song-service`:

```
server:
  port: 8082

spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      host: mongodb-container
      port: 27017
      database: music
  application:
    name: SONG-SERVICE


eureka:
  client:
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://service-registry-container:8761/eureka/

  instance:
    hostname: service-registry-container
```

3. `application.yml` of `service-registry` (Eureka server):

```
server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
```

4. `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"
services:

  service-registry-container:
    image: service-registry
    ports:
      - 8761:8761
    networks:
      - ms-music

  album-service-container:
    image: album-service
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    networks:
      - ms-music

  song-service-container:
    image: song-service
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    networks:
      - ms-music

  mongodb-container:
    image: arm64v8/mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes: 
      - ~/mongo/data:/data/db
    networks:
      - ms-music

networks:
  ms-music:
```

Any tips on how I can replicate the local behavior on a docker container?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options:

### Use the container name as host

Since all your containers are within the same docker network, using a container's name INSIDE any given container will resolve to the correct container (thats a lot of containers lol). In your case the hostname would be `song-service-container` if you want to resolve to your songService.

### Use host.docker.internal

If all the containers run on the same machine, you can try to put `host.docker.internal` as the host. It will resolve to your local machine, and sincethe ports of the containers are forwarded to your machine's, that should work too.

Comment: As for using container name as host, you still need to provide the port number, as I've done in service-url.defaultZone : http://service-registry-container:8761/eureka/. Is there a way i can get around to not using the port number?